# How this regex work?

Tags: regex

can you explain this regular expression.

```
$price = "...555.55";
$price  = preg_replace('/^./', '', $price);
```

output:

```
 $price = ..555.55;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex `'/^./'` matches any character at the beginning of the string.

- `dot(.)` matches any character except the `newline` character, and
- `caret(^)` is used to match at the beginning.

So, your `preg_replace` is replacing any character at the beginning with an empty string.
So, `...555.55` becomes `..555.55` after replacing the first `.`.

If you just want to replace all the `dots(.)` from the beginning, then you have to escape the `.` in your regex. Since simply using `.` will match any character. Also, you need to use some quantifier - `*` or `+` to replace more `dots(.)`.

So, your regex would be:

```
preg_replace('/^[.]+/', '', $price);
```

or:

```
preg_replace('/^\.+/', '', $price);
```

Comment: how its replace first charater only............ if i want to replace first 3 char na........

Comment: `^.` regex matches just one character at the beginning. Since you haven't used any quantifier. So, it replaces just the first character.

Comment: @Malai.. Seems like you want to replace all the `dots` at the beginning, for that, you have to escape the `.`, to match the dot. So, your regex would be: - `/^[.]+/`, and replace it with `""`. Note that when you use just `/^./`, it will even replace `X` from the beginning, since `.` matches anything. To replace just the `dot(,)`, you can escape it, or use a character class.

Comment: r u have any link for regex tutorial

Answer (score 1):

`/^./` matches the first character after the start of the string.

- `/` and `/` delimit the regex.
- `^` matches the position at the start of the string,
- `.` matches any character unless it's a linebreak).

That match will be replaced by the empty string (`''`).

If you want to replace the first three characters:

```
$price = preg_replace('/^.{3}/', '', $price);
```

If you want to replace all dots at the start of the string, you need to escape them and apply a quantifier (`+` meaning "one or more"):

```
$price = preg_replace('/^\.+/', '', $price);
```

If you want to replace all non-digits at the start of the string (which might make more sense):

```
$price = preg_replace('/^\D+/', '', $price);
```